# Spring AOP self injection makes other autowired/injected objects null

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I am try to log time using Spring AOP.

The Logging AOP looks like:

```
public class TimeLogger2 {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.exercise.spring.aop.service..*(..))")
    private void anyOperationInControllerPackage() {
        /* nothing to do here;
         * this just defines that we want to catch all methods
         * in the controller-package
         */
    }

    @Around("anyOperationInControllerPackage()")
    public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Entering " + joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + "#" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "() using arguments: " + Arrays.toString( joinPoint.getArgs() ) );

        try {
            Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

            System.out.println("Leaving " + joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName() + "#" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "()." );

            return result;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

```
package com.exercise.spring.aop.service;
import ....

@Service
public class MyService {

    private TestService testService;

    @Autowired
    MyService self;
    
    public MyService(TestService testService){
        this.testService = testService;
    }

    public void mymethod(){
        self.sample2();
    }
    
    private void sample2(){
        System.out.println("Inside Sample2" + testService);
    }
}
```

As you can see the "self" variable is used for self injection.
The logging works fine, but if i try to access any autowired objects like `testService` in the method `sample2()`, it is `null`.

How can I access the testService which is autowired in this example?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work without AOP? Because it looks to me as if you're trying to mix constructor and field autowiring, between which you'd need to decide. Ie add a `MyService` parameter to the constructor and remove the `@Autowired` annotation from the field.

Comment: @daniu then it will throw cyclic dependency error.

Comment: Is the requirement to get the `testService` instance within your advice ?

Comment: @R.G , i need the testService in the second method to perform some tasks. But I need to log using aspect for every method in the MyService class. The logging works fine, but the testService is null in the nested methods. Any autowired objects are null in the nested methods.

Comment: The method is private and thus invoked on the proxy and not on the actual object. Make it `protected` or `public` else it won't work.

Comment: Oh I just realized that `self` is the same as the declaring class. What do you expect to be injected, the `MyService` bean itself? Why not just use `this`?

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks a lot, it worked. I recall now that private modifier are tricky in spring.

Comment: Your problem with `private` is not about Spring, it is just Java. Subclasses cannot access private members or methods of their parents and a dynamic proxy is a subclass (at least a CGLIB proxy is, a Java proxy technically implements an interface, i.e. only deals with public methods by definition). It is as simple as that.